# Difference between Linearfrom and Vector

Tags: differential-forms

What is actually the difference between a linear-form, or more specific, a Differential-form and a Vector? The differential of the function $f$ seems like the gradient just in the basis of the $k$-form.

Comment: Linear forms are actually vectors themselves, but from a different space

Comment: @caverac In a Book I have read, they said linear form and Vector are from 2 different nature. That's why we should forget about rotation and divergenz, it is only d.

Comment: It is true they are from a different nature. To give you an example, imagine that $V$ is a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) and $v \in V$ is a vector. Also assume that $V^*$ is the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) of $V$, an element $w\in V^*$ is a vector of $V^*$, but also a linear functional that takes a any element $v$ and gives you back a number $w(v)\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @caverac Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for.